# Q: How to find the next word of a specific word in a txt-file

Tags: python, data-analysis, txt

New here!
I am searching for the following or the next word for the word "I". Ex "I am new here" -> the next word is "am".

```
import re
word = 'i'
with open('tedtalk.txt', 'r') as words:

pat = re.compile(r'\b{}\b \b(\w+)\b'.format(word)) 
print(pat.findall(words))
```

```
with open('tedtalk.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        phrase = 'I'
        if phrase in line:
            next(f)
```

These are the codes i have developed so far, but i am kind of stuck already. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options.

first, with split

```
with open('tedtalk.txt','r') as f:
    data = f.read()

search_word = "I"
list_of_words = data.split()
next_word = list_of_words[list_of_words.index(search_word) + 1]
```

second, with regex:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r"\bI\b\s*?\b(\w+)\b")
with open('tedtalk.txt','r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
result = regex.findall(data)
```

Comment: Thank you! What about if i wanted to find the following word for "I" and not the first "I" in the given line? :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your first piece of code, `words` is a file object, and there will be problems with line-by-line verification. For example, in the following case, `am2` may not be found.

`tedtalk.txt`

```
I am1 new here, I 
am2 new here, I am3 new here
```

So I modified the program and read 4096 bytes multiple times to prevent the file from being too large and causing the memory to explode.

In order to prevent the data being truncated causing it to be missed, the `I` will be looked for from the end of the data for a single read, and if found, the data following it will be truncated and put in front of the next read.

```py
import re

regex = re.compile(r"\bI\b\s*?\b(\w+)\b")


def find_index(data, target_value="I"):
    """Look for spaces from the back, the intention is to find the value between two space blocks and check if it is equal to `target_value`"""
    index = once_read_data.rfind(" ")
    if index != -1:
        index2 = index
        while True:
            index2 = once_read_data.rfind(" ", 0, index2)
            if index2 == -1:
                break
            t = index - index2
            # two adjacent spaces
            if t == 1:
                continue
            elif t == 2 and once_read_data[index2 + 1: index] == target_value:
                return index2


result = []

with open('tedtalk.txt', 'r') as f:
    # Save data that might have been truncated last time.
    prev_data = ""
    while True:
        once_read_data = prev_data + f.read(4096)
        if not once_read_data:
            break
        index = find_index(once_read_data)
        if index is not None:
            # Slicing based on the found index.
            prev_data = once_read_data[index:]
            once_read_data = once_read_data[:index]
        else:
            prev_data = ""
        result += regex.findall(once_read_data)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['am1', 'am2', 'am3']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
search_word = 'I'
prev_data = ""
result = []
with open('tedtalk.txt', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        data = prev_data + f.readline()
        if data == prev_data:  # reached eof
            break
        list_of_words = data.split()
        for word_pos, word in enumerate(list_of_words[:-1]):
            if word == search_word:
                result.append(list_of_words[word_pos+1])
        prev_data = list_of_words[-1] + ' '
print(result)
```

I modified the code to read the text file by line, this should handle unlimited large file. The code also addresses the case where the search word is the last word on a line by taking as next word the first word of the next line.

If you rather treat each line independently and ignore the search word if it is the last word in the line, the code can be simplified as follows:

```
search_word = 'I'
result = []
with open('tedtalk.txt', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        data = f.readline()
        if not data:  # reached eof
            break
        list_of_words = data.split()
        for word_pos, word in enumerate(list_of_words[:-1]):
            if word == search_word:
                result.append(list_of_words[word_pos+1])
print(result)
```